# ZK + RapidSpell Checker Integration?

Tags: javascript, zk

From last couple of days i was trying  to integrate **RapidSpell Checker** with **ZK Web application** and i am able to run the demo code [Here](http://zkframeworkhint.blogspot.in/2013/06/integration-of-rapid-spell-checker-with.html) you can get the demo code. Now when i am going to use same code in my web application if my page is individual page everything worked fine but when my page is created dynamically inside a tab from below code

```
Executions.createComponents("/my_detail.zul", comp, arguments);
```

While i added the above line in the **zul** file

```
<?script type="text/javascript" content=" zk.afterMount(function()
{rsw_setupTextBoxes(true);});"?>

    <script src="a.rapidspellweb?t=r&amp;n=RapidSpell-AYT.js" />
     <script type="text/javascript">
        rapidSpell.setParameterValue('default', 'UserDictionaryFile',
        '~/userdictionaries/1.txt');
    </script>
```

Which is needed to run Rapid Spell checker.

Here you can see the demo **zul** which is working fine.

```
<window title="Hello World!!" border="normal" width="100%" >
    <?script type="text/javascript" content=" zk.afterMount(function()
{rsw_setupTextBoxes(true);});"?>
    <style src="./sans-style.css" />
    <script src="a.rapidspellweb?t=r&n=RapidSpell-AYT.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        rapidSpell.setParameterValue('default', 'UserDictionaryFile',
        '~/userdictionaries/1.txt');
    </script >
    <label value="You are using: ${desktop.webApp.version}" />
    <textbox rows="10" ></textbox>

</window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean it works fine if link to the page directly but some js errors happened if the page is created dynamically?

This probably caused by run some code that should be run 'after' js library is loaded too early, you can try something like below:

```
var initTimer = setInterval (function () {
    if (window.rapidSpell) {
        rapidSpell.setParameterValue('default', 'UserDictionaryFile',
            '~/userdictionaries/1.txt');
        clearInterval(initTimer);
    }
}, 500);
```

Edit: Apply the edit provided by subodh joshi, replace zscript part with javascript

Call required functions by javascript,

e.g.,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <![CDATA[
      zk.afterMount(function(){
             setTimeout(function() { rapidSpell.setParameterValue('default', 'UserDictionaryFile', '~/userdictionaries/AmandaDic.txt');}, 2000); 
             setTimeout (function () { rsw_setupTextBoxes(true);}, 4000); });
    ]]> 
</script>
```

Comment: I am not getting any exception but spell checking not working when page have inner zul.How can i send you the Sample war?Please let me know any email id

Comment: You can download from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/zkspellchecker/files/zkspellchecker.war/download

Comment: you can see here in index.zul spellchecker working but its not working when modal window open.

Comment: The problem is that the afterMount function is not called when the modal opens, so rsw_setupTextBoxes is not called.  What you need is an event that is fired when a modal is opened.

Comment: As mentioned by Jim W, please refer to the updated content. But it comes another issue, js error happened after the textbox in the modal window is clicked.

Comment: @Ben there is no any solution of this issue. and this is not happening in modal Window also when i am creating a tab and then add zul same issue i am getting

Comment: I tried it in IE and it works for me, until I clicking the textbox, could you provide a snapshot or flash demo to describe this issue further?

Comment: In your example where you used  <script src="a.rapidspellweb?t=r&n=RapidSpell-AYT.js" /> style? also can we ignore zscript and used something else is production zscript disable

Comment: OK, I have to define the code in parent zul as well as child zul then it work but i will want to remove zscript how can i get it?

Comment: Ok i found the solution and edited the answer as well hanks @ben and  jim

Comment: Hi ben i am trying to add some more code in your answer but someone removed that code 2times